# Adding jQuery effects to mobile device - effects work on desktop/tablet but not iPhone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I just built my first serious webpage, and now I'm noticing none of the cool jQuery effects I put in there are working on an iPhone.  Is there a simple solution to this problem?

There is no AJAX and the effects are mostly for hiding/showing divs and adding replacing `.val()`.

If this question is too generic, then please suggest where I might read up on the subject.  Thanks.

Here's my javascript/css loading in head:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" /> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/application.js"></script>
```

Here's an example of some jquery, please assume all these variables and methods work on the desktop in `application.js`:

```
    homeButton.on("click", function(){
    about.fadeOut(300);
    gallery.fadeOut(300);
    contact.fadeOut(300);
    rules.fadeOut(300);
    download.fadeOut(300);
    home.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
});

contactButton.on("click", function(){
    home.fadeOut(300);
    gallery.fadeOut(300);
    about.fadeOut(300);
    rules.fadeOut(300);
    download.fadeOut(300);
    contact.delay(300).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Other than that I'm just doing some stuff with vals:

```
    nameBox.on("focus", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Name') {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
nameBox.on("blur", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val('Name');
    }
});
```

Comment: It would help if you could post some code?

Comment: I agree with Iharby. I fail to see why simple things like `hide()`, `show()`, `val()` wouldn't work. What exactly are you doing? and how? Its almost a guarantee that if it works on a mobile platform its going to likely work on a desktop. My first guess would be, that your not loading in files in the proper order. Or they can't be found during the pages render time.

Comment: You may want to clarify what libraries you're using. There's no such thing as "mobile jQuery" but there *are* three distinct libraries - "jQuery", "jQuery Mobile" and "jQuery UI"

Comment: So are about, gallery, contact etc variables that you are using to store further information. I would vote that you post something in jsfiddle, and then it can be tested by the community.